# Calculating the frequency of each row in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have given datasets:

```
Sr.No|Query
-----
 1.   a
 2.   a
 3.   b
 4.   b
 5.   a
```

I want the following result :

```
Sr.No | Query | Frequency
1.    a         3
2.    a         3
3.    b         2
4.    b         2
5.    a         3
```

Please note that the duplicates should not be removed.

Comment: Can you explain how you arrive at the frequency here? also please edit your question so it looks presentable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df['Frequency']= df.groupby('Query')['Query'].transform('size')
print (df)
   Sr.No Query  Frequency
0    1.0     a          3
1    2.0     a          3
2    3.0     b          2
3    4.0     b          2
4    5.0     a          3
```